# asp.net mvc 2: Overriding client validation so i can use jquery effects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

is there a way to override client validation so i can use jquery?

Currently i am using attributes on my model, a new feature of mvc 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is included in MVC futures.

Look in `\mvc2-rtm-sources\src\MvcFuturesFiles\MicrosoftMvcRemoteValidation.js`

Answer (score 0):

check out the xVal project:  http://xval.codeplex.com/

I think by default it's wired up to use jQuery validation, but you can substitute your own validation logic if you want.